# UL listing of a fan

Tags: ul

An electrical Inspector has stated he cannot accept our fan for use in an industrial diesel Exhaust removal system since the entire fan does not show a UL listing number. We have tried to explain that only the motor needs to be UL listed. He counters this, stating there is a new US Governmental regulation requiring the entire fan to be UL listed. UL-705 exempts these type fans. I think one of us is in error, who?

Comment: This question would be a better fit on [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com). I have flagged it for migration, but you might want to search there and see if your question has been asked before.

Comment: A significant number of inspectors are. This is irrelevant. Does he quote the new regulation? Does it date after UL-705. If it uses the words "Homeland security" or anything else similar or related in the wording just give in. The only solution is to move to NZ and start over. You may have to revoke your US citizenship. This may not be enough.

Comment: Ask the inspector to look at UL705, Clause 1.2 (tells you what is not covered) r) (says gases other than air?? )  and see what  the response is. I suspect it may be covered by a different standard, probably to do with fume extraction, but I couldn't find anything for diesel fumes....